# How to make PGP's output less verbose in mutt with GnuPG & TOFU?

Tags: mutt, gpg, pgp, gnupg

I recently added `trust-model tofu+pgp` in my `.gnupg/gpg.conf` to use [TOFU](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2015-October/054608.html) and automatically trust (marginally) keys from e-mails I see for the first time. It has the bad consequence of making PGP's output horribly verbose:

```
gpg: Verified 1 message signed by "Foo <foo@foo.org>" (key: F00 BA8 …, policy: auto) in the past 32 minutes, 19 seconds.
gpg: Warning: we've only seen a single message signed by this key!
gpg: Warning: if you think you've seen more than 1 message signed by this key, then this key might be a forgery!  Carefully examine the email address for small variations (e.g., additional white space).  If the key is suspect, then use 'gpg --tofu-policy bad "name_of_key"' to mark it as being bad.
```

PGP's output appear *before* the body of the message, and worse, this blob of text appears once for each e-mail address associated to the key. On my small screen, I have to scroll a lot before reading the actual e-mail. I'm looking for ways to fix that:

- is there an option in mutt that allows to display only a summary of PGP's output (95% of the time, all I care about is "did the verification work, and what's the level of trust associated to key")?
- if not, is there an option to display PGP's output *after* the body of the message instead of before?
- otherwise, is there a way to make GnuPG's output less verbose?

Thanks in advance! I use GnuPG 2.1.11 with mutt 1.5.24 on Debian Sid (4.3.3-5; kernel 4.3.0-1-amd64).

Comment: I'm not aware of a better solution but writing a GnuPG wrapper (script) hiding those information.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout
http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?topic=t-prot

This is actually intended to filter out the quoted thread below the mail (TOFU acronyme clash), but also has a few pgp options. It can be activated by putting something like

`set display_filter="t-prot -M mutt --pgp-move --pgp-short"`

into your .muttrc
(do not forget to install t-prot in the first place)

Unfortunately it does not remove the terrible parade of warning blocks you are mentioning, but this is the best ready-made that I could find.

Of course, you can filter through your own script as well.

**Edit:**
Since I had the same Problem and getting gawk or alike to do the job was ... I wrote my own script. Feel free to use this as the display filter:
https://github.com/Echsecutor/mutt_gpg_display_filter/blob/master/filter.py